# Degree of an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, intuition

I am learning about the degree of algebraic sets. I know the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_an_algebraic_variety) from Wikipedia, but it is not too clear to me what it is. Could someone possibly explain to me exactly what property the degree of an algebraic set does capture, or how I should think about it?

---

<sub>PS: This was part of another question of mine, [Basic question regarding degrees of algebraic sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348589/basic-question-regarding-degrees-of-algebraic-sets), but I thought that maybe it would be better to ask this separately.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Degree is best thought of as a property of projective varieties, since in $\mathbb{C}^n$, a linear space is not an intrinsic property. For example, in two variables, $x=0$ and $x=y^2$ define indistinguishable varieties, but the degrees of their equations are different. On the other hand, in $\mathbb{P}^n$ varieties are defined as zeroes of homogeneous polynomials. In particular, one would like to say that a hypersurface defined by a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ has degree $d$ as a variety. This can be translated as, if we intersect the hypersurface with a 'general' line, we should get $d$ points. So, the degree of an arbitrary projective variety of dimension $r$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the number points in the intersection of the variety with a general linear subspace of dimension $n-r$. That this intersection is in fact a finite number of points and independent of the linear space as long as it is general are somewhat technical theorems. Of course, take some of this with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer! Could you possibly explain a little more what is meant by general line? when you say: intersect the hypersurface with a 'general' line. Thanks!

Comment: The set of lines in projective space is parametrized by a Grassmannian. So, this set has a natural variety structure. General means they come from a suitable non-empty open subset of this Grassmannian. Think of a quadric in projective plane. The special lines would be tangent lines, general lines the rest.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. Thank you very much! By the way if you feel like it please look at my other question mentioned in the PS as well! :) It's also about degree of algebraic sets. I put a bounty but there hasn't been too much activity and it is going to expire soon...